# What international border crossings link Turkey, Georgia and Russia?

Tags: russia, borders, turkey, georgia-country

Looking to travel from Turkey into Georgia and then Russia with motocycle

**What international border crossings link Turkey Georgia and Russia?** 
Is it possible to go by ferry from Turkey to Russia?

Comment: Potentially interesting: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/crossing-from-georgia-into-turkey?rq=1 http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-the-border-between-georgia-and-russia-open-to-citizens-of-other-countries and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/921/ferry-connection-between-crimea-ukraine-and-georgia

Comment: Turkey and Georgia have two border crossings. The big one on the Black Sea coast and the smaller one on the road that connects to Kars. For a motorbike tour I recommend the latter but if you're doing a quick commute the former. The Georgia/Russia crossings are in a state of flux but I believe you should be able to cross via Abkhazia or the one that leads into Chechnya. The Batumi-Sochi ferry was halted last I checked but the Batumi-Ukraine ferry was operating. This is a comment rather than an answer because it all changes frequently and I'm not up to date right now.

Comment: Indeed, everything I've read says that Batumi-Sochi ferry, IF operating, is for Russian citizens only at present.

Answer (score 4):

overland, you can cross from Turkey to Georgia at the Sarp border crossing.
From Georgia you can cross to Russia at the Kazbegi - Verkhni Lars border crossing.

I did both border crossing last year, no problems if you have the necessary visas.

Sarp border crossing is very modern, quick and easy. in about 20 minutes you're on the other side.

Regarding Kazbegi-Verkhni Lars:
AFAIK, no visas are being issued at the border. If you get there, you need to have all the relevant visas in your passport beforehand.
If you don't need a visa either to Russia or Georgia - you need nothing, just get there and easily cross to the other side (from both sides).

As to October 2012, the border was not open all day. As far as I remember it was open at 8:00-21:00 (maybe 7:00-22:00).

Moreover, the crossing was slow, as there was a big line, and each car was being checked (roentgen check). It took me about 2 hours to cross each time. If you arrive earlier, it is better.